# Count number of occurences in JSON object using ALASQL

Tags: javascript, json, alasql

I am trying to count the number of occurrences of certain property(TypeAlarme in my case) in a javascript object using **ALASQL**.
Here is what i have tried

```
let data = [{DepName: "Dept Test Code Blanc2",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 1"},
             {DepName: "Dept Test Code Blanc2",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 3"},
             {DepName: "Dept Test Code Blanc2",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 2"},
             {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 1"},
             {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 3"},
             {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 3"},
             {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 1"},
             {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 2"},
             {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 1"},
             {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 2"},
             {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 3"},
             {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 3"},
             {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 1"},
             {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 2"},
             {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 1"},
             {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 2"},
             {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 3"}];
 
let deptList = alasql('SELECT COLUMN DISTINCT DepName FROM ?',[data]);//List of departments    

let etats = alasql('SELECT COLUMN DISTINCT TypeAlarme FROM ?', [data]);//List of etats

let counts = [];

deptList.forEach((i, dept) =>
{
    let countsByDept = [];
    etats.forEach((j, etat) => 
    {
       let count = alasql('SELECT COLUMN COUNT(TypeAlarme) FROM ? WHERE DepName = ? AND TypeAlarme = ?',
                                                                  [data, dept, etat]);
                countsByDept.push(count[0]);
    });
    counts.push(countsByDept);
});
console.log(counts); // returns [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]] should be [[1, 1, 1], [5, 4, 5]]
```

My goal is to count how many etats for each departments. For department 'DeptTagWiFi' we have 5 occurrences of 'BtnEtat 1'; 4 occurrences of 'BtnEtat 2' and 5 occurrences of 'BtnEtat 3. For department 'Dept Test Code Blanc2' we have 1 of each 'BtnEtat 1' 'BtnEtat 2' and 'Btn Etat 3'.

Comment: I was going to say you can't do anything useful with JSON until you parse it ... then I realised your code has no JSON in it ... anyway ... what does your current code do? how is that different from what you want it do do? Also, given the data, which of the datum is department 'A' and why does it have 5 'BtnEtats' - could you be clearer in your requirements

Comment: I added more details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with non useful indexes (i, j) in the forEach loops.

```
let data = [{DepName: "Dept Test Code Blanc2",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 1"},
         {DepName: "Dept Test Code Blanc2",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 3"},
         {DepName: "Dept Test Code Blanc2",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 2"},
         {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 1"},
         {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 3"},
         {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 3"},
         {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 1"},
         {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 2"},
         {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 1"},
         {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 2"},
         {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 3"},
         {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 3"},
         {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 1"},
         {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 2"},
         {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 1"},
         {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 2"},
         {DepName: "DeptTagWiFi",TypeAlarme: "BtnEtat 3"}];



let deptList = alasql('SELECT COLUMN DISTINCT DepName FROM ?',[data]);//List of   departments    

let etats = alasql('SELECT COLUMN DISTINCT TypeAlarme FROM ?', [data]);//List of etats

let counts = [];

deptList.forEach((dept) =>
{
    let countsByDept = [];
    etats.forEach((etat) => 
    {
       let count = alasql('SELECT COLUMN COUNT(TypeAlarme) FROM ? WHERE DepName = ? AND TypeAlarme = ?',
                                                                  [data, dept, etat]);
                countsByDept.push(count[0]);
    });
    counts.push(countsByDept);
});
console.log(counts); // returns [[1, 1, 1], [5, 5, 4]] which is correct
```